# mysql column name increment by 1

Tags: mysql, database

Is there a way to create a table automatically that have column name increment by 1, from 1 to n, in procedure?

So the table can be this if n = 4
id, col1, col2, col3, col4

It can also be like this if n = 7
id, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7

Comment: Why not use descriptive column names like *Name*, *Address*, etc.?

Comment: Any reason why you would want to do that? Maybe there is another way to solve your provlem

Comment: You would have to do this using application code or a complicated loop and `CONCAT()`  within a MySQL procedure, and it can be done. But I have to ask - is it really something that needs to be done? Wide tables like this can usually be made unnecessary by thinking differently about the database design.  For example, reformatting it into a `key,value` schema instead of variable table columns.

Comment: Those columns are temporary and are used to store calculations. Depending on the user input, the number of columns needed varies.

I need to do it in SQL since that is the requirement of the assignment.

Comment: You need to better explain why you'd need to do this in the first place, perhaps with an example of the sorts of calculations you're doing. Normally you can do `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE x SELECT y,z FROM a` if you need dynamic control.

Comment: Each column is the weight*values and each column has different weight

Comment: Sounds like either a really bad requirement, or maybe the requirement was misunderstood?

Comment: Is bad requirement.  I manage to use a loop and concat() to create the sql statement. It wont work in the procedure but if I copy the sql into the box in phpmyadmin and it will work.